# Python Unzip file

Tags: python, tkinter, zip

Really inexperienced with python and still learning. I am trying to unzip a file with the click of a button. When I run this program the GUI does not show the button.

```
from zipfile import ZipFile
import Tkinter


top = Tkinter.Tk()
top.title("NAME of Program")


def Unzip():
with ZipFile ('Test.zip', 'r') as zipObj:
    zipObj.extractall()


UnButton = Tkinter.Button(Text="Unzip", command = Unzip)


top.mainloop()
```

Comment: The text on a Button is specified by a `text=` option, not `Text=`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few changes you need to implement.
First import "tkinter", not "Tkinter". Second, you need to change "Text" to be "text". Finally, you need to pack the button using "UnButton.pack()"

```py
from zipfile import ZipFile
import tkinter  # Changed


top = tkinter.Tk()  # Changed
top.title("NAME of Program")


def Unzip():
    with ZipFile ('Test.zip', 'r') as zipObj:  # Adding a Tab (4 spaces)
        zipObj.extractall()


UnButton = tkinter.Button(text="Unzip", command = Unzip)  # Changed
UnButton.pack()  # Added


top.mainloop()
```

Comment: excellent commenting on what was changed to correct the code.

Comment: @D.L Thank you. I appreciate that <3

Comment: OP does not say which python is used, so `Tkinter` is valid if OP uses Python 2.x.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I rewrote it using the canvas method, as this will allow you to have more control over your application for positioning, add images, add shapes move shapes. Hope this helps, happy coding!!

```
from zipfile import ZipFile
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.title("NAME of Program")
canvas = Canvas(width=500, height=500)
canvas.pack(fill="both", expand=True)


def unzip():
    with ZipFile('Test.zip', 'r') as zipObj:
        zipObj.extractall()


UnButton = Button(text="Unzip", command=unzip)
# First value is x coordinate, horizontal axis, second value is y coordinate vertical axis, window should equal the Variable of the
# tkinter widget
# you can create as many windows for canvas as you need for each element
canvas.create_window(235, 150, anchor="nw", window=UnButton)

mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Code is fixed. 'UnButton.pack()' is added in code.

> Follow this link to understand Widget.Pack() method
>
> https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/tk_pack.htm

```
from zipfile import ZipFile
import tkinter


top = tkinter.Tk()
top.title("NAME of Program")


def Unzip():
    with ZipFile ('Test.zip', 'r') as zipObj:
        zipObj.extractall()


UnButton = tkinter.Button(text="Unzip", command = Unzip)
UnButton.pack()


top.mainloop()
```